# How can I write a SQL Server stored procedure to get the following output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, stored-procedures

I have a `SourceTable` like this with 2 column names:

```
  Col 1  | Col 2
------------------
  A      |   2
  B      |   3
  C      |   4
  D      |   2
  E      |   1
  F      |   0
```

The first column has some letter, and the second column carries its frequency.

We need to write a stored procedure and get the output in a `TargetTable` like this.

We **CAN NOT** use any loop, or iteration for this.

```
Col 1
-----
  A
  A
  B
  B
  B
  C
  C
  C
  C 
  D
  D
  E
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a recursive CTE?

```
with x as (
      select col1, 1 as i, col2 as lim
      from t
      where col2 > 0
      union all
      select col1, i + 1, lim
      from x
      where i + 1 <= lim
     )
select col1
from x
order by col1;
```

Comment: col1
-----
A
B
C
D
E
D
C
C
C
B
B
A


This is what I get for your code

Comment: @CodeFearer  You just need to add an `order by` clause.

Comment: just add order by 1 to get it exact as you want

Comment: You'll want `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` in there for non-trivial values of `Col 2`

Comment: Be aware that recursive query is usually significantly slower than table of numbers or other methods of generating a series: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Comment: Thank You so much @iamdave That was indeed so silly of me.. But just another silly query. :'( How do I modify the code to insert the result into TargetTable??

Answer (score 0):

Assumes there is a low known max value for Col2 (in this case 10):

```
  select Col1 from tbl
  inner join (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) T(n) 
  on T.n <= tbl.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a table of numbers. For example, see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

It is a table `Numbers` that has one column `Number` with values from 1 to some large enough amount. I personally have a table of numbers with 100K rows. It is possible to [generate it on the fly](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1), but it is handy in many cases, so I have a permanent table.

```
SELECT
    A.Col1
FROM
    SourceTable
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT SourceTable.Col1
        FROM Numbers
        WHERE Numbers.Number <= SourceTable.Col2
    ) AS A
ORDER BY Col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a recursive cte or have a table of numbers, you can use `master..spt_values` to generate your numbers for you:

```
declare @t table(Col1 nvarchar(1), Col2 int);
insert into @t values
 ('A',2),('B',3),('C',4),('D',2),('E',1),('F',0);

with rn as
(           -- This sub select simply makes sure you only get the maximum number required.
select top (select max(Col2) from @t) row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn
from master..spt_values t1
    cross join master..spt_values t2
)
select t.Col1
from @t t
    inner join rn
     on(t.Col2 >= rn.rn)
order by t.Col1
```